# Show/hide labels in an XForms drop down list

Tags: xml, xpath, constraints, xforms

Hi I am trying to use XPath to dynamically show/hide options in my XForms drop down list.

Here is the XML with my drop down list:

```
<xml_someField>
  <label>Podmiot</label>
  <hint/>
  <help/>
  <alert/>
  <item>
    <label>1</label>
    <value>1</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <label>2</label>
    <value>2</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <label>3</label>
    <value>3</value>
  </item>
  <item>                  
    <label>4</label>
    <value>4</value>
  </item>
</xml_someField>
```

Basically I have an `other_field` which give me output for example - 1, 1 2, 1 3, 1 2 3 4 ect. depending on what I check in another combobox.

So, in my drop down list in **calculate** I wrote an XPath expression

```
if(//other_field != '') then 
if(//other_field castable as xs:integer) then 
     //other_field
    else .
else
    false()
```

If I get from other_field only one number - 1, 2, 3 or 4 it's work, it's fill my xml_someField with chosen number, but if I get more then one for example - 2 3 4 or 1 3 4 it's give me too choose all 4 options.

All i want is, when I get 1 3 4, that in my drop down list show 1, 2 and 3 options without 4.

I can recognize number using

```
if(contains(//othe_field, '1') then
```

But what next, is there any method to show/hide item label or value?

```
//other_field/item/label[text() = '1'] = false()
```

And should I wrote this in **calculate** or maybe better in **constraint**?

Answer (score 0):

> All i want is, when I get 1 3 4, that in my drop down list show 1, 2 and 3 options without 4.

Use a constraint:

```
 constraint=". &lt; 4"
```

> And should I wrote this in calculate or maybe better in constraint?

Use a `constraint`, because calculated values automatically become readonly

**References**

- [XForms Tips: Using Calculations](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xformstipcalculations/)
- [XForms: The constraint property](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#model-prop-constraint)